# Raspberry Pi has text input lag, but only within apps (browser & VS Code)

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, vnc-viewer

I'm trying to run Raspberry Pi Headless, connecting VNC viewer through SSH.
It appears to work fine, except for huge lag (a few seconds for whatever I typed to show on the screen) when using some apps - the default browser, or  VS Code. However, when I type into the Pi's terminal from my PC through VNC viewer, there is no lag whatsoever - even if I have VS Code and the browser open at the same time.

Setup, for info:
Raspberry Pi 4 (4mb) (xmas present, so a new one, although the SD card is a good few years old repurposed from a digi cam)
Wired Ethernet to windows pc.
Installed software: Raspbian v11 OS, and VSCode with a python extension

Grateful for any advice!?

Update:
In case this might have been an issue, some digging around made me question the (32gb) SSD card, so ran the raspberry Pi SSD diagnostics tool. The card failed the test, but wasn't so off target.
Average of 6 passes...
Sequential write speed: 10500 / 10000 PASS
Random write speed: 175 / 500 FAIL
Random read speed: 1350 / 1500 FAIL